# Create form action as variable

Tags: asp.net, forms, webforms, action

I have t following ASPX source :

```
  <form name="AddComment" action="ViewArticle.aspx?ArticleID=<%=ArticleID %>" method="post" runat="server">
```

The problem is that when I click submit I got this url

```
http://localhost:61175/WebSite1/ViewArticle.aspx?ArticleID=%3C%=ArticleID%20%%3E
```

But I want get this URL :

```
http://localhost:61175/WebSite1/ViewArticle.aspx?ArticleID=1
```

If I delete the "runat="server"" command it works fine, but can this form work *with* the 
variable  and the runat server at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try setting the action just before the form markup like this (or in codebehind, at your choice)

```
 <%
     this.Form.Action = "ViewArticle.aspx?ArticleID=" + ArticleID.ToString();
 %>
 <form name="AddComment"  method="post" runat="server">
```

Comment: How can I put the code in the codebehind page? When I do it I get an error

Comment: @NaveTseva works fine here, with the exact same line as first line of page_load. What is the error you get ?

Comment: @NaveTseva might be many reasons, because the form is not available at that moment ( in a usercontrol, added dynamically, with an ancestor or itself being Visible=false, ...)

Answer (score 1):

In server side controls you can't do such things as <%= ActionID %> you can only bind <%# ActionID %>.

The upper solution won't work, becouse the form is not that form. You have to give a control ID + name than setup the post url. If it's not an option you can dinamicly search for form item in the control tree, so dynamic ID-s can be handled.

Comment: Compared to other controls, Form has a special status : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.form.aspx